# Openid php library: can't get nickname and other profile info

Tags: php, openid

I tried the Openid library.
I put openid URL https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id
Looks like it is working fine as it authenticate me, but it doesn t return nickname email and other data as required 
Thx for any hints about

Answer (score 2):

You have to request that data by using the attribute exchange extension. See [here](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html).